# Thumping and scraping sounds

Tags: corolla, drivetrain

I recently bought a 1995 Toyota Corolla that has been in a wreck.

When accelerating, there's almost always a thumping sound that increases with tire speed. It gets louder if I turn left and goes away when I turn right. Sometimes when I make a harder left, the car will also make a metal scraping sound. This seems to mostly happen if there's a dip in the road on a slow left.

Apparently in the wreck one CV axle was bent, and the other was broken. I talked to the towing place I bought it from and they won't give me any more information. I've also noticed the passenger side front lower control arm is bent. It looks like the towing company bent it back by hand.

Where should I start? CV axle, hub or something else?

Comment: You don't say what country you are in, but in the UK a cheap (and fixed price) way to get an professional inspection with no sales pitch attached is to take the car for an MOT safety test. The only downside is that if the tester decides it is so unsafe as to be unfit to drive, you will have to tow it away from the test site.

Comment: Have you checked to ensure the wheels are round? What you describe could easily be a bent rim.